# Pytest - how to find the test result after a test

Tags: python, pytest

After a test has been executed I need to collect the result of that test. But I don't find the result in the FixtureRequest object. I can find the test name and some additional data but nowhere I see something that shows if a test has been passed or failed. Nor if there were some exceptions

example code:

```
class TestSomething:
    @pytest.mark.test_case_id(99999)
        def test_example(self, api_interface) -> None:
            assert 5 == 5
```

and in someother file:

```
@pytest.fixture
def api_interface(request: FixtureRequest):
```

I can see that the request has the title name and a node object but nowhere I see something result or assert like data....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve this is by using [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#collection-hooks). The hook will add the test result as an attribute of the test item, which afterwards you will be able to check and perform necessary actions.

```
# example conftest.py
import pytest


# set up a hook to be able to check if a test has failed
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)


# check if a test has failed
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def test_failed_check(request):
    yield
    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        # Do something if tast has failed
        print('Test Failed')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is also to use the following hook:

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    if report.when == 'call':
        outcome = report.outcome
```

The report object will hold different properties like outcome, failed and so on. This hook will be executed after each test. That case you can report directly after a test has been executed.

Sidenote: this function needs to be put in the conftest.py file!